# JQuery Library Conflicts

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I'm not sure how to incorporate the two jquery libraries that I need to operate slidedeck and lightbox concurrently. If I remove "jquery.js", slidedeck will work but lightbox won't. If I remove "jquery-1.3.2.min.js", on the other hand, lightbox will work but sliddeck won't.

Trying to run them both at the same time results in slidedeck working / lightbox broken, and generates the following report in Google Chrome:

[image: [Error Msg in Chrome]]

Can anyone help me figure out how to run both of these jquery plugins at the same time?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace both those with this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JQuery is up to 1.6.4 man, gotta keep up :)

Comment: Not really answers the question, but I agree. He should just update all 3 (jQuery, lightbox and sidedeck) to the latest version and not include 2 versions of jQuery.

Comment: @Alien: Thanks. It works now, but any clue as to why the lightbox moves a lot more slowly now? To clarify, moving between images when hitting "next" or "previous" is a lot slower after making this change.

Comment: Nope I'd need to see your site and step through the before/after code.  Is your lightbox code up to date?

Answer (score 2):

> If I remove "jquery.js", slidedeck will work but lightbox won't.

When you remove `jquery.js`, Lightbox does not work because you're including it BEFORE `jQuery-1.3.2.min.js`.  In other words, with that particular instance of jQuery removed, you're including Lightbox without jQuery at all.

jQuery has to be included **before** any/all plugins.

> If I remove "jquery-1.3.2.min.js", on the other hand, lightbox will
>   work but sliddeck won't.

That's probably because `jquery.js` is out of date.

Just include the latest version of jQuery **ONCE, and before** you include both plugins.

Answer (score 1):

use noConflict

```
<script src='jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>
<script>
var jq132 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script>
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

use the appropriate versions with the suitable plugins like **(the codes do not depict how the plugins are actually used but added just for clarity)**

```
jq132("element").sliddeck(); // i don't know about sliddeck so don't know how to use
```

and

```
jq142("element").lightbox();
```

as @Sparky672 indicated you have to include `jquery` before you include any other `xyz.js`

Comment: Since plugin was likely defined as `jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() { ... }` it will likely be applied to the last jQuery instance included.

Comment: You have a period after the `jq142` in your second example.

Comment: Just because noConflict will allow the OP to run two versions of JQuery doesn't mean we should be suggesting that as a "solution".